# Vectors 2D first usage

Tags: c++, vector

It is my first time to use 2D vectors in C++ and it seems that I'm trying to access forbidden location although the indexes of the loops are less than it is size

```
int generate_(vector<int> row,vector<int> column)
{
    int i=1,j=1,k=0,l=0;
    vector<vector<int > >matrix;//2D vector


    for(k=0,l=0;l<column.size();l++)
    {
        matrix[k][l]=row[l];
        cout << matrix[k][l]<<endl;
    }

    for(k=0,l=0;l<row.size();l++)
        matrix[l][k]=column[l];

        for(i=1;i<row.size();i++)
        {
                for(j=1;j<column.size();j++)
                {
                matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j-1]+matrix[i-1][j]+matrix[i-1][j-1];

                }
        }
    return matrix[i-1][j-1];
}
```

Comment: Of course you are. You haven't set the size of the `matrix`. It's empty now.

Comment: i thought its auto allocated

Comment: The vector has a variable size, but that size need to be set first. See the answers and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

matrix is not initialized, it has no elements so matrix[k][l] will raise an exception

Comment: If `matrix` is `vector<vector<T>>`, it won't raise an exception, it will forcecrash on dereferencing null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding you tried to initialize data in the matrix, but you have to allocate memory for this matrix before initialization.

change this line

```
vector<vector<int > >matrix;//2D vector
```

to

```
vector<vector<int > >matrix(column.size(), vector<int>(column.size(), 0));
```

Equal to:

```
vector<int> intVector(column.size(), 0)
vector<vector<int > >matrix(column.size(), intVector);
```

[image copied from www.stackover.com, but I lost the original post id]
[image]

Comment: i replaced this line and worked well , but iam not familiar with this vectors' definition can you explain it to me or provide me with a source  ?

Comment: The vector is very similar to array in C++. Say we do "int arr[];" It does not allocate any space for it. When we do "int arr[5];" It allocates space on stack. The vector constructor vector<T>(4, something) means we allocate 4 items on the stack memory. Each is "something". One example is vector<int>(4, 100); is a vector of 4 integers of value 100. See  vector constructor reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ A general guide to vector http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

Comment: vector<vector<int > >matrix(column.size(), vector<int>(column.size(), 0)); i understood this example except vector<int>(column.size() this parameter

Comment: In the code I added the equivalent. It is like, this array holds 4 of intVector's. In the original line I called the constructor directly like vector<int>(column.size(), 0). The return value of a constructor is the object (instance of a class). If we do this vector<int> intVector(column.size(), 0); the result is we create an object on the stack. In this problem two different approaches serve the same purpose

Comment: If you wonder why 0, it does not have to be 0. it can be any value since the value will be change in the code following it.

Comment: iam not wondering why 0 , i wonder what is 
 vector<vector<int > >matrix(column.size(), vector<int>(column.size());
what is column.size() ,and vector<int>(column.size())  is it eq to row and column in array 2D decleration

Comment: vector<vector<int > >matrix(column.size(), vector<int>(column.size(), 0)); In this statement the first column.size() is the row size, the second is the column size. This line of code is saying, now I am going to allocate an array of (column.size()) amount of arrays. Each subarray also allocates (column.size()) amount of 0's on the stack. See the image on my post too.

Comment: then we can write the statement in this way vector<vector<int>matrix(row.size(),column.size(),0);

Comment: This statement does not follow any of vector's constructors. Why doesn't STL provide a constructor taking two dimensions' sizes? vector<T> is actually one dimensional, like array of integers (vector<int>) or array of floats (vector<float>). When we make it array of array, it becomes two dimensional (vector<vector<T>>). We even can make it multiple dimensions, don't we? (vector<vector<vector<T>>>). Because this extensibility, STL designers do not provide more than necessary constructors.